# Prof Lewandowski's paper about different space time for different particles

Tags: specific-reference, loop-quantum-gravity

I read here http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/07/130709115344.htm that Prof. Lewandowski's work suggests that different particles may experience different spacetimes. His work is in the context of Loop Quantum Gravity. Sadly there is no reference to the original paper. Can anyone provide it?

Comment: I know nothing about these models, but a bit of searching turn's up [Lewandowski's arxiv page](http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Lewandowski_J/0/1/0/all/0/1), [research gate page](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jerzy_Lewandowski/) and a [preprint of the article that this piece seems to be about](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0161).

Comment: @Nivalth: it is not just about the inconsistency and indefensibility of LQG. It is about the utterly irrational and biased approach that its decided champions that includes you pursue. How can you possibly study some bizarre, non-elementary, derived, speculative conclusion of LQG before you study LQG itself? Don't you realize that you can't possibly end up with anything else than gibberish? You should start to study LQG as a theory first. If you do it right, you will understand why it's inconsistent. If you can't quite do it, fine, you may "study" the claim by Lewandowski later.

Comment: Otherwise I find the last paragraph of your question totally unacceptable for a questions-and-answers server. If you're asking about some question related to LQG in this case and the crux of the answer is that some claims made somewhere about LQG are incorrect and must be replaced by other, correct claims, then it is absolutely essential for a good answer on this server to point this fact out. Your last paragraph is trying to censor some inconvenient facts. It's not really a question. It's an advocacy of a flawed theory - one that you don't even know.

Comment: @LubošMotl I've removed the flamebait paragraph.

Comment: @LubošMotl thanks for your comments, and sorry if you found my last paragraph offensive in some sense. I don't know LQG myself and I don't have the intention of study of the field at this moment (as I don't even have the physical and mathematical basis to do it) I just came across a claim made within the context of this theory, and I wanted to ask some information about it, maybe a not too technical explanation (which I'm not given at the moment). What I'm given, besides a link which I'm thankeful for, is your opinion about LQG, which I already knew. Nothing about that particular claim.

Comment: Dear @Nivalth, this more general question would be more appropriate. The article is a hype ignited by the fact that the paper got to a journal. But it is a 2-citation preprint after half a year, so it's fair to say that it hasn't excited even the loop quantum gravity community. All the interpretations in the media (and even in the paper) are loaded. What they have found is that the Lorentz symmetry is broken in LQG/LQCosmology even if one tries to assume it is preserved, and the dispersion relations are modified as a function of velocity etc.

Comment: Needless to say, in the real world, the dispersion relations aren't modified in this way so the prediction of LQG is safely falsified. This is just another example showing the general principle that LQG is fundamentally in conflict with the theory of relativity, so even if one makes the unjustified assumption that something fixes the problems for the gravitational part (which almost certainly doesn't occur), the violation of Lorentz symmetry re-emerges as soon as we ask another question (in this case the propagation of a Klein-Gordon scalar particle on the background), thus ruling LQG out.

Comment: It's disingenious for them to put a positive spin on this result and claim that this is a real wonderful new prediction about the Universe around us when it's obvious to everyone who follows what's going on that this prediction is spectacularly wrong.

Comment: @LubošMotl thank you for your comments, they were very useful :)

Comment: Nivalth, I made an edit to the question that I think should remove the problems people had with it that were causing them to cast close votes. Feel free to revert the edit if you like, but do note that a few people thought the question in its old form was not sufficiently clear, and I'm inclined to agree with them.